# Why does HBase's managed zookeeper service fail with "The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper"?

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

TL;DR: Why does HBase-managed Zookeeper fail to start?

I am trying to set up an HBase cluster to learn HBase from scratch.  I have 4 Virtualbox VMs running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server.  I have Hadoop (2.7.3) installed with a master and 3 worker nodes.  They each have 2 ethernet adapters, 1 in NAT mode and 1 in host-only network mode (per Virtualbox).  They are 192.168.56.50 (master) and 192.168.56.51-53 (workers).

When I installed HBase 1.2.4, I tried to set it up with the Zookeeper quorum on all 3 worker nodes, managed by HBase.  This would not run.  I tried wiping out the Zookeeper data folder on all worker nodes and then reducing the zookeeper config in hbase-site.xml to a single-node quorum on the first worker, and it still does not work.

In hbase-env.sh I have

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

In hbase-site.xml I have

```
    <property>
            <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
            <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
            <value>192.168.56.51</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
            <value>2181</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
            <value>/usr/local/zookeeper/data</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
            <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
   </property>
```

On the master server, in the master.log file I get

```
"ERROR [main] client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master."
```

and in the master.log I get

```
"RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1484535638771, pause=100, retries=1}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master."
```

and lots of

```
2017-01-15 21:59:11,236 INFO  [main-SendThread(192.168.56.51:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server 192.168.56.51/192.168.56.51:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2017-01-15 21:59:11,237 WARN  [main-SendThread(192.168.56.51:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

followed by

```
2017-01-15 21:59:26,761 ERROR [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper create failed after 4 attempts
2017-01-15 21:59:26,761 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:2426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2436)
```

On the node that is supposed to be the sole Zookeeper node, the zookeeper.out file is empty and the zookeeper.log file contains lots of

```
[main-SendThread(192.168.56.51:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server 192.168.56.51/192.168.56.51:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2017-01-17 21:50:32,343 WARN  [main-SendThread(192.168.56.51:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

**Why is it failing?  I cannot find any good explanation for what's going wrong.**

Comment: Lets start with simple check: is ZK listen on 192.168.56.51:2181?
*netstat -at | grep 2181*. Second problem that I see in logs: HBase try access invalid znode /hbase, but your hbase-site contains /hbase-unsecure. Check that all HBase nodes have identical hbase-site.xml.